# How to describe dad's reaction in English?

Tags: expressions

[image: How to describe dad's reaction?**Thank you**]

Can anyone help to describe dad's reaction when he heard that the kids needed so much money? I mean the behavior, water came out of his mouth, can I say 'spray' or 'spit'? Can anyone tell me the complete sentence, please?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The action of the father is also (very) casually known as "doing a spit-take" - "The father is doing a spit-take"/"The children made their father do a spit-take"

Comment: Oh yes yes, spit-take. That's the word I'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, Priya. A correct answer (and new to me), but ELU expects supporting references to accompany answers. It would also be correct to indicate that this usage is 'informal' or even 'slang' if the dictionary you choose adds this caveat.

Answer (score 0):

> aghast

[TheFreeDictionary: aghast](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/aghast)

taken as an adjective:

> horrified, shocked, amazed, stunned, appalled, astonished, startled, astounded, confounded, awestruck, horror-struck, thunder-struck

at being asked for a large sum of money.